# How can I export whatsapp chat to my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing an app, where user can export chat from WhatsApp and then can upload on my flutter app database. I don't know how to do this. Though we can open WhatsApp from

```
  url_launcher
```

and
from

```
 get_it
```

but I wanna export whole chat. Thank You

Comment: You cannot export the chat from WhatsApp, because WhatsApp secures it, you can do it only manually

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain how to manually please?

Answer (score 3):

I just released a new package for exporting whatsapp chats to flutter app.

See - https://pub.dev/packages/receive_whatsapp_chat

Import my package, and follow the steps.

After you imorted my package and follow the steps, you will need to go to whatsApp, export a chat to your flutter app and you will receive the chat analyzed: chat members, chat name, messages per member, size of the chat and all of its messages.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @LW001 No, sometimes we don't know about a tool that should not be followed.